# Stripe create transfer to a card

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Is this possible to create a transfer in a Card Token?

Like that for example :

```
stripe.transfers.create({
    amount:2000,
    currency:"usd",
    destination:"tok_194738183747"
})
```

Or have I to create account and transfer to this account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to create transfers to card tokens.

Transfers can be used to move funds:

- from a Connect platform's balance to one of it's connected accounts' balance, a.k.a. a ["special-case transfer"](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers)
- from a Stripe account's balance to one of its external accounts

In the latter case, the "external account" is, in most cases, a bank account. The only exception is that US managed accounts may use a debit card as an external account to receive funds.

Here's the documentation for managing transfers for managed accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-transfers.

Comment: So how can I process if I want to give money to one of my customers ?